# How to compile and run files from a java package in Ubuntu sublime-text3?

Tags: java, package, sublimetext3, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to compile files from a java package in sublime-text3 for Ubuntu 18.04.

I found the following code for java.sublime-build:

```
{
   "shell_cmd": "javac \"$file_name\" && java \"$file_base_name\"",
   "shell": true,
   "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
   "selector": "source.java",
}
```

and it works fine when all the classes are defined in the same file. 
However, my current case involves class definitions in different files (hence the use of a package), and I can't make the parser recognize the class:

```
RunParser.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
        MSTparser testParser = new MSTparser("1.333", "word");
        ^
  symbol:   class MSTparser
  location: class RunParser
RunParser.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
        MSTparser testParser = new MSTparser("1.333", "word");
                                   ^
  symbol:   class MSTparser
  location: class RunParser
2 errors
```

When I compile the files and run from terminal, it all works fine:

```
javac mstparser/*.java && java mstparser.RunParser
```

In the java.sublime-build file, I have tried changing to:

```
"shell_cmd": "javac \"*.java\" && java \"mstparser.$file_base_name\"",
```

also with no success.

Comment: Putting `*.java` in double quotes stops the shell from being able to expand the glob, so I would imagine that the Java compiler tries to compile a literal file named `*.java` in that case. Removing the quotes might fix the problem, but all else being equal you're better off using a dedicated Java build tool like `ant` and having the build system invoke that to do the job instead.

Comment: @OdatNurd: You were right about the double quotes. Now, the execution of the file fails:
'Error: Could not find or load main class RunParser
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mstparser/RunParser (wrong name: RunParser)'
I tried hardcoding  `java mstparser.RunParser` and get a similar error

Comment: @OdatNurd: regarding `ant`, it doesn't seem to integrate with sublime, does it?

Comment: There's a default `Ant.sublime-build` that will invoke `ant` if you're editing a Java file and there is a `build.xml` file in the project path, so in theory it should work, though you would have to construct the `build.xml` file yourself (unless there's a package to help with that, but I'm not sure)